# Failure of N.R.T.L method to model Phenol / Methylcyclohexane / Toluene system in AspenPlus. Why?

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering, modeling

I have an extractive distillation column set up in AspenPlus. Methylcyclohexane (MCH) is expected to come out from the top (in the distillate stream) and the bottoms stream is mostly Toluene/Phenol, with a bit of MCH. The feeds are MCH+Toluene (at stage 8 out of 25) and Phenol (at stage 18 out of 25).

Temperature - 100 C. Pressure - 1 atm.

When I use the N.R.T.L (non-random two-liquid) model for the simulation, I get weird results. However, when I use UNIFAC, I get what I expect.

I thought NRTL was supposed to take into account deviations from ideality (caused by the phenol group?), so I don't know what's throwing it off.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about temperature and pressure?

Comment: Good catch. Edited. (100 C, 1 atm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At moderate temperatures and pressure NRTL should be a good option provided that the binary interaction parameters are correct.

You need to check:

1. Whether the binary interaction parameters for your three compounds are in Aspen Plus database. If not, try to find them in literature or, use UNIFAC to determine only the unknown parameters (most process simulators allow you to do that).
2. If the three binary interaction parameters are in the Aspen Plus database, check whether they represent the experimental behaviour of your system. In particular, try to reproduce binary Pxy and/or Txy diagrams. Otherwise, try to reproduce any experimental bubble or dew point information you might have.

Of course, if you don't have good binary interaction parameters, UNIFAC being totally predictive is a good choice. As you know, UNIFAC divides a molecule into groups which contribute differently to the Gibbs free energy. The compounds you mention can be decomposed into fairly standard groups (you can check the list [here](http://www.ddbst.com/published-parameters-unifac.html#ListOfMainGroups)) and UNIFAC results should be reliable.

Finally, I have to say that, though uncommon, it may happen that process simulators contain errors in interaction parameters (NRTL, Wilson, UNIQUAC) or similar that lead to poor predictive capabilities. I did work in a project (mostly confidential) where a widespread process simulator completely failed to reproduce the VLE behavior of something similar to 2-butanol in water/methanol solution because the interaction parameters were wrong. We detected it comparing with experimental data of Txy and we regressed and corrected the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

One more question, where did you get the binary interaction parameters? Have they been process or experimentally validated?

My understanding if NRTL from a high level is that it is good for modelling of non ideal or polar vle if the interaction parameters are correct.

This could mean validating the interaction parametrs in the range in which they are used.

Please reply with what you find out!

Comment: I did not specify my own binary interaction parameters. I see the Aspen database has a default set though.

Comment: Ok. I wonder if BIPs are the problem rather than NRTL. Interesting article https://www.advantage-marketing.com/content/uploads/2015/11/thermo_article.pdf. It might be interesting to run with another activity model (Wilson?) if there are coefficients for your mixture and see how it compares.